# Service invoked too many times in a short time: urlfetch. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My function is showing this error for a few days, before it worked normally. I really don't know how to insert a fix for this problem. Thank you very much in advance.

```
Service invoked too many times in a short time: urlfetch. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls.
myTrivia    @ TRIVIA.gs:14
```

This is my code:

```
function myTrivia() {
  var f = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('TRIVIA');
  var data = new Date();
  data = Utilities.formatDate(data, "GMT-03:00", "yyyy/MM/dd");
  f.getRange('F1').setValue(data);
  var url = 'https://triviapw.com.br/cotacao/api/item/';
  var [h, ...v] = f.getDataRange().getValues();
  var reqs = v.map(([a]) => ({
    url,
    method: "post",
    payload: {id: a, date: data, server: h[6]},
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  }));
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(reqs);
  var values = res.map(r => {
    var str = r.getContentText();
    if (r.getResponseCode() == 200 && str != "Requisição inválida") {
      var obj = JSON.parse(str);
      return [obj.nome, obj.venda, obj.compra];
    }
    return Array(3).fill("");
  });
  f.getRange(2, 2, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

After using the code suggested below (by @Tanaike), the system reports the following "Invalid request" and after "Exceeded maximum execution time"

I tested an alternative for just one line and it worked normally (this was the old code)

Here's the code:

```
function myTrivia() {
  var f = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('TRIVIA');

  
  var formData = {
    'id': f.getRange('A2').getValue(), //A2 IDitem
    'date': f.getRange('F1').getValue(), //F1 Date
    'server': f.getRange('G1').getValue(), //G1 ServerName
  };
  
  var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'payload': formData
  };
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://triviapw.com.br/cotacao/api/item/', options);
  var response = JSON.parse(result.getContentText());
  var res_code = result.getResponseCode();
  if (res_code == 200) {
    f.getRange('B2').setValue(response.nome); //name item
    f.getRange('C2').setValue((response.venda + response.compra) / 2); //midle price for test
  }
}
```

Comment: In order to understand your situation, can I ask you about the number of rows in your current Spreadsheet? Namely, it's the length of `v` in your script.

Comment: Hello how are you? So my spreadsheet has 116 rows

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood your current number of rows. And, about `Service invoked too many times in a short time: urlfetch.`, in your situation, how do you run the script?

Comment: I think it will be easier if you can see it. It reads the data from column A and enters the information into columns B, C, and D.

Please note: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u3zT3xKl8FAnCQEY3tPqZ4CX3yFHr-R_1lerh-vo0Ps/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I usually update it once or twice a day at most.

Comment: From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful for your actual situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `So my spreadsheet has 116 rows` and `I usually update it once or twice a day at most.`, I thought that in this case, your error message of `Service invoked too many times in a short time: urlfetch.` might not occur. So, I'm worried about other reasons.
But, if you want to use `UrlFetchApp.fetch` instead of `UrlFetchApp.fetchAll`, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myTrivia() {
  var f = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('TRIVIA');
  var data = new Date();
  data = Utilities.formatDate(data, "GMT-03:00", "yyyy/MM/dd");
  f.getRange('F1').setValue(data);
  var url = 'https://triviapw.com.br/cotacao/api/item/';
  var [h, ...v] = f.getDataRange().getValues();
  var values = v.map(([a]) => {
    var r = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { method: "post", payload: { id: a, date: data, server: h[6] }, muteHttpExceptions: true });
    var str = r.getContentText();
    var res;
    if (r.getResponseCode() == 200 && str != "Requisição inválida") {
      var obj = JSON.parse(str);
      res = [obj.nome, obj.venda, obj.compra];
    } else {
      console.log(str); // If an error occurs, you can see the error message at the log.
      res = Array(3).fill("");
    }
    Utilities.sleep(2000);
    return res;
  });
  f.getRange(2, 2, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- In this modified script, each request is run with the synchronous process. And, each request is run by `Utilities.sleep(2000)`. Please adjust the value of `2000` of `Utilities.sleep(2000)` for your actual situation.

#### Reference:

- [sleep(milliseconds)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds)

### Added:

When you want to use the script for retrieving one value from one row as a custom function, how about the following sample script? In this sample script, please put a custom function like `=myTrivia(A2)` to a cell. By this, the script is run for one row.

```js
function myTrivia(id) {
  var max = 2; // Number of retry request.
  var [date, server] = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("F1:G1").getDisplayValues()[0];
  var retry = 0;
  do {
    var url = 'https://triviapw.com.br/cotacao/api/item/';
    var r = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { method: "post", payload: { id, date, server }, muteHttpExceptions: true });
    var str = r.getContentText();
    if (r.getResponseCode() == 200 && str != "Requisição inválida") {
      var obj = JSON.parse(str);
      return [[obj.nome, obj.venda, obj.compra]];
    }
    retry++;
    Utilities.sleep(2000);
  } while (retry < max);
  return [Array(3).fill("")];
}
```

- In this sample script, when 1st request occurs an error, the request is retried. Even when 2 requests are done, when an error occurs, the empty value is returned. You can adjust the number of retry with `max`.